# Issue in chrome with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla

I am working on jquery and javascript. i am using an external library to make a function to work. but the code works fine with firefox. but the issue is with chrome. its not working like mozilla. since i am very new to this field i have googled and didnt find a solution. do i need to install any chrome extension file for this.  any help would be appreciated. here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
     <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>login testing</title>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
       $(window).load(function(){
      $(function()
       {
        $('#submit').click(function()
          { 
              $('.container').show();
              $('#login').hide();
                $.cookie('shown', true);
                });
              if ($.cookie('shown')) {
                  $('#submit').click()
              }
            });
         });  

       </script>


         <div id="login">
             <form id="loginform">
                 Uname:
                    <input type="text" id="uame" name="uname">

                 Pwd:
                    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">

                <div class="Button1">
    <button type="button" id="submit" value="Login" class="btn" >
                        Submit
                    </button>
    <button type="reset"  id="reset" value="Reset"  class="btn">
                        Clear All
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>

                        </div>


                   <div class="container" style="display:none">
                Welcome to the naughtyprogrammer website    
                    </div>


               </body> 

               </html>
```

Comment: first of all, try to replace `$(window).load(function(){` by a `$(document).ready(function(){`. If you still have problems, try with this plugin. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie . It works like a charm in Chrome too

Comment: @TCHdvlp: i have tried replacing $(document).ready(function(){. but unfortunately it didnt work. and  i am looking for this solution for a long time. any idea. Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your cookie ? If it doesn't persist as you wish in chrome, it may be because by default, the lifetime of the coockie is the session (not written I know, just look for the cookie in chrome and you will see that). The solution is to force the lifetime like this `$.cookie('shown', true, {expires : 365});` for instance

Comment: @TCHdvlp: i am very newto this cookies concept. and i even added $.cookie('shown', true, {expires : 365});. but doesn seemed to work.

Comment: Is it normal that the `if(cookie){...click()` isn't in the `$("#submit").click(` function ? I don't understand the purpose of your code. Anyway, You can log the cookie value in the console `console.log($.cookie('shown'));` to see if it's undefined or not. also, you can check for a specific cookie in chrome. Search for localhost cookies if your are runing a local server.